# onSelectionChanged in EditText class

Tags: android, cursor, selection, android-edittext, invoke

Why this metod called just on finger click on Edittext, and dont called when you change cursor position by keyboard? Is there a method that is invoked every time?

Comment: I am chasing a problem related to this. In answer to your question: On some mobiles it IS called, and on others it is not..... both > 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard and touch navigation are quite different.

Selection doesn't change with keyboard navigation until you click. Generally cursor movement isn't a useful feature to track.

Comment: So is it possible to get the current line number ,without dividing measure of text on height and others strange methods?